# PrimeUI Rating component not working

Tags: jquery, primefaces, prime-ui

I'm using jquery 1.9 and primeUi 1.0
My primeUI widgets are working fine except rating component.
PrimeUI rating component not displaying either. Is their any problem in PrimeUi rating component? I have tried following code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
       $('#rating').puirating();
     });
 </script>

 <input id="rating" type="hidden" />
```

Their is no error in Firefox error console.

Comment: Did you try `$(window).load` rather than `$(function)`?

Comment: Yes I tried but result is same.. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Works fine in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eha6uhcc/1/%20JSFiddle). Did you include jQuery UI as well?

```
<input id="rating" type="hidden" />
$('#rating').puirating();
```